# Loading modules in angular2 application on the fly

Tags: module, ionic-framework, angular, components, lazy-loading

In my current angular 2 (ionic) project I'm trying to achieve the following. I have a base application which authenticates a user to a known backend. When this is done, the user receives a number of modules he can use. These modules are separate bundles that are fetched from the server at runtime.

The logical view is something like this:
[image]

So, there is an application server that holds the server side of the application, and there is a device side of the application that is installed. Only the green parts are always there. The blue parts (the modules) are deployed separately and are loaded only then a user has access to it.

The modules use a shared services API (networking, authentication, access to device specific features via Cordova etc.) and have their own, also seperately deployable webservices on the appserver/backend.

I would like to give a module programmer the opportunity to create an angular component that consumes a webservice and use the shared API. How can I load a component from the appserver into my app running on the device?

[edit]
Q: Can you give an example of a loaded module?

A: Basically it can be anything that consumes a webservice deployed on the appserver. In a normal case it would consist of a combination of html and javascript (perhaps with some additional css).

Let's say we have a list of persons in the database, and a webservice that queries it, then the device gets a angular component with templates (I was thinking of the Ng2 version of a templatecache js file) which it should 'inject' into the running application.

It should be remarked that a restart of the application on the device is not out of the question.

Comment: Can you give an example of the module loaded on demand?

Comment: @AngJobs See my edit.

Comment: @tuvokki have you seen how you can "compile" an angular2 component programatically.. basically you can have a service that lives in the app which from your server gets a description on how to create a component like the one that you need. Based on this description it will compile a component and you will be able to use it.. And I am not sure how this will work if you need a router..

Comment: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/loading-components-dynamically-in-angular-2.0 is a good read for dynamically loading components

Comment: @tuvokki any luck on this? I am looking into the same problem and I cannot seem to find resources that describe how to use angular 2 router in ionic 2. my lazy loaded modules need to use routes.